# Can't View Thumbnails when trying to open JPEG files

Tags: windows-7, images, jpeg, thumbnails

In Photoshop, I put in a CD with my images, when I try to select a file, I can't view the thumbnails.  Only the Photoshop icon!  It showed the actual picture before, and all of a sudden it stopped!  So frustrating!

Answer (score 0):

1. Ensure you're not using *Details*, *List* or *Small Icons* view in Windows Explorer.
2. Under Organize > Folder and search options > View tab, ensure *Always show icons, never thumbnails* is not selected.